# iOS GPS Tracking app shutdown in background

Tags: ios, objective-c, gps, afnetworking, background-process

I'm currently working on an iOS app using objective-C that send every minute gps coordinates to my API.

I've used `AFNetworking` & `CoreLocation`, I also wanted my App to run all day long, but only send coordinates if time is between 8am - 6pm.

Everything's working fine on iOS simulator targetting iOS9 my app is sending his location every 1 minute to my API, even if i press home or lock the phone.

`PhoneCall`, loss of network or GPS have been handled in order to keep my task running.

But when I tested it on some device (iPhone 4S on iOS9) Location stop updating after an average time of 1hour to 1hour and a half.

Is iOS shutting down my app in background after a given time?

If so, is there a way to keep my app doing her job in background for at least 10 hour, without having to prompt the device user?

Implementing long running background task are "allowed" by apple if it concern:

"The app keeps users informed of their location, even while it is running in the background."

Does that mean background task will block my http request after a while?

For long term deployment, I wish my app to be upload on the App Store, but I've read many post about app GPS tracking app which have been rejected.

Here's the minimal list of requirement my app should have:

- Send GPS coordinates to my API every minute
- Working in background for a minimum time of 10 hours without shutting down or prompting user to reload the view

Could those requirement be accepted to get my app upload on AppStore?

Or will I have to use local/remote notification and prompt the user to reload my app in order to keep it running for such a long time?

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation says.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

*The significant-change location service is highly recommended for apps that do not need high-precision location data. With this service, location updates are generated only when the user’s location changes significantly; thus, it is ideal for social apps or apps that provide the user with noncritical, location-relevant information. If the app is suspended when an update occurs, the system wakes it up in the background to handle the update. If the app starts this service and is then terminated, the system relaunches the app automatically when a new location becomes available. This service is available in iOS 4 and later, and it is available only on devices that contain a cellular radio.*

I think this will be apt for your scenario.